# How to use mittag-leffer expansion to compute $\texttt{sech} z$? A question concerning a paper from Kesten (1986)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, proof-verification

In Kesten's 1986 paper (Limit distribution of Sinai's Random Walk) we read:

[image]

The reference  is E.T. Whittaker and G.N. Watson, A Course of Modern Analysis, 4th ed. (Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 1952).

We see that:

[image]

Using this result we can begin to do some manipulations:

First write
 $$\frac{1}{\cosh(\sqrt{2\theta})} = \texttt{sech} \sqrt{2\theta} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4\pi (2k + 1) (-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2\pi^2 + 8\theta} $$

Then we come back to the expression we are interested in:

$$\Bbb{E}\{ e^{-\theta L}; L>0\} =\frac{1}{2\theta} \bigg[1 - \texttt{sech}(\sqrt{2\theta})\bigg]\\
= \frac{1}{2\theta} \bigg[1 - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4\pi (2k + 1) (-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2\pi^2 + 8\theta}\bigg]  $$

But how do we obtain the second line
$$ \frac{16}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^\infty    \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k + 1)}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2\pi^2 + 8\theta} ?$$

Comment: Frankly I do not understand this idea of using the site as a personal notepad.

Comment: @Did Have you ever asked someone a question and during the process you found that you understood much better the problem and sometimes you also found the answer to your problem? This is what happens to me. Besides, it becomes a useful record for me (and others) that might have the same  troubles reading the same lines in the future. But maybe this isn't the place for this discussion. And quite frankly, I appreciate your comments ;)

Comment: Sure it can happen, but not systematically. Anyway, the third sentence of your own comment seems to destroy the fairytale you propose in the first two sentences, doesn't it?

Comment: @Did, no fairy tales here. By the way, what is the sentence you refer to and what is it destroying?

Comment: "what is the sentence you refer to" Quote: "the third sentence of your own comment", and later on, "the first two sentences".

Comment: @Did I do have trouble understanding your point here, let me suggest a better place for this discussion. You probably know it already, but I state here for your convenience: Its the Meta of Math stackexchange. To better inform our discussion I suggest you remember once again the advices on how to use the site namely: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and also https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Comment: Sorry but I made my point, rather clearly I think. No doubt you are *allowed* to post involved questions only to answer them instantly, no doubt one can find this is not the most useful way to approach the site (and I find telling that you reduce my first comment to a legalistic problem).

Comment: Dear @Did behind the laws there is "L'esprit des lois". You started the conversation sharing some troubles you have to understand the idea of using the site as a personal notepad. I only tried to give you my perspective. If you are looking for a better explanation (since mine apparently is rather insufficient) you might find them with the spirit that guided people to write these aforementioned advices, namely stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and also meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice. I assume you want to understand things you don't understand.

Comment: Maybe I was too polite and maybe you pretend to miss the point, which is quite obvious: no, math.se was not thought and made for the way you used it with your two last "questions", hence in this case, *L'Esprit des lois* is saying the opposite of what you pretend. Is it a big deal? No. Is it annoying that you run to legalese to avoid the point? Mildly. Is there anything else to wax on about this strange practice of yours? Not much (fortunately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that $\texttt{cosh} (0) = 1$ so

$$ 1 = \frac{1}{\cosh(0)} = \texttt{sech} (0) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4\pi (2k + 1) (-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2\pi^2 }$$

Therefore

$$ \Bbb{E}\{ e^{-\theta L}; L>0\} =\frac{1}{2\theta} \bigg[1 - \texttt{sech}(\sqrt{2\theta})\bigg]\\
= \frac{1}{2\theta} \bigg[ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4\pi (2k + 1) (-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2\pi^2 } - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4\pi (2k + 1) (-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2\pi^2 + 8\theta}\bigg]\\
=\frac{4\pi}{2\theta}\bigg[\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{8\theta (2k + 1) (-1)^k }{(2k+1)^2\pi^2} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2\pi^2 + 8\theta}\bigg]\\
=\frac{16}{\pi}\bigg[\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^k }{(2k+1)} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2\pi^2 + 8\theta}\bigg]$$

which is the desired result

Comment: With $K=k$. $ $

Comment: many thanks!! :)